# jQuery autocomplete not picking data from php

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to do an autocomplete while typing in an input, this is what I tried so far:

jquery

this is placed under `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "../inc/search.php",
            minLength: 1
        });
```

PHP page:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

    $return_arr = array();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT Username FROM USERS WHERE Username LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%' .$_GET['term']. '%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] = $row['Username'];
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

but it doesnt work, I type "andrei" for example and it says "No search results."

## SOLVED

Instead of ../connect.php I used connect.php

Answer (score 0):

I think that your path is not OK.

```
source: "../inc/search.php"
```

try with

```
source:  "/inc/search.php"
```

Comment: My include was incorect
was ../connect.php instead of connect.php, thanks anyway!